# (Photo) My App Script not working (on mobile) when I add custom domain to Google Sites, On destop browser no proplem

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sites, godaddy-api

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQyLW.png)
my source
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiwdg.png)

I tried opening incognito browser and it didn't work (it can't be displayed on mobile browser but still works on desktop switch to mobile interface)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHWtR.png)

Comment: Learn how to post code [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.